# iOS UIButton with multiple labels

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

I have a UI button that I'd like to put two labels on it, similar to how a cell has a title text and detail text.

I'd like the button to have a larger font for the main text, and have smaller detail text under that.

Is this possible?  I've tried to put multiple lines on a button, but I need to have different text sizes for each line, so setting the lineBreakMode and numberOfLines of the titleLabel doesn't really quite work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code we finally used.  Assistance from John Wang.

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions!

```
// Formats a label to add to a button.  Supports multiline buttons
// Parameters:
// button - the button to add the label to
// height - height of the label.  usual value is 44
// offset - the offset from the top of the button
// labelText - the text for the label
// color - color of the text
// formatAsBold - YES = bold NO = normal weight
// tagNumber - tag for the label

- (void) formatLabelForButton: (UIButton *) button withHeight: (double) height andVerticalOffset: (double) offset andText: (NSString *) labelText withFontSize: (double) fontSize withFontColor: (UIColor *) color andBoldFont:(BOOL) formatAsBold withTag: (NSInteger) tagNumber {

    // Get width of button
    double buttonWidth= button.frame.size.width;

    // Initialize buttonLabel
    UILabel *buttonLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, offset, buttonWidth, height)];

    // Set font size and weight of label
    if (formatAsBold) {
        buttonLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    }
    else {
        buttonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    }

    // set font color of label
    buttonLabel.textColor = color;

    // Set background color, text, tag, and font
    buttonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    buttonLabel.text = labelText;
    buttonLabel.tag = tagNumber;

    // Center label
    buttonLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    // Add label to button
    [button addSubview:buttonLabel];

    [buttonLabel autorelease];
} // End formatLabelForButton
```

Answer (score 4):

A trick I would recommend is putting a UIButton with a transparent interior on top of UILabels.  I've used this trick before and, although it may present some problems in terms of maintenance and i18n, it works like a charm.

Here is a 5 minutes sample using the suggestion above.
[image: Label behind button]

Given more time, you can make a better label with round corners.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this would require me to create a view with a background for the button, and I'd like to just have two different font styles on the button ideally.

Comment: @Orangemako when you use @Gordon suggestion, give the label background a different color.

Comment: this will have no animation

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to add subviews to it. Since everything is a view, everything can potentially have subviews.

I would subclass it and put the labels on it within the subclass, Then you can extend properties for text and subtext to change their values.

Not saying it can 100% work. But off the top of my head. UIView can have SubViews